# How to stop getting "Refused to frame..." message with Azure AD B2C in a Blazor WebAssembly App

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

When setting up Azure AD B2C support for a Blazor app,
we are getting the error below when selecting the Twitter Identity Provider,
the flow works ok though when using Facebook Identity Provider.

We need to be able to support Twitter,
does anyone knows how to stop getting this error in a Blazor app

**"Refused to frame 'https://api.twitter.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"**